# 14.04 on Asus GL552JX: Fn+F5 and Fn+F6 Brightness Problem

Tags: 14.04, brightness, asus, function-keys

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on my ASUS GL552JX. The one that always bugs me is the `Fn`+`F#` button functionality.

---

This time, all `Fn`+`F#` button combinations work except for `Fn`+`F5` (brightness down) and `Fn`+`F6` (brightness up). I've tried some solution from the internet such as changing the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

inside `/etc/default/grub` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and other solution such as adding:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

into `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, but no option works.

---

Current condition:

- I can change brightness via brightness slider in `System Settings > Brightness & Lock`.
- I've installed bumblebee and nvidia driver (GL552JX has Intel HD and Nvidia GPU). But I haven't activated the Nvidia card yet.

Any help?

Comment: Do Fn brightness keys work or not? You wrote that they DO work.

Comment: Edited the ambiguous part. They (Fn+F5 and Fn+F6) don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be fixed in 3.19 kernel.

1. Install 3.19 kernel by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`.
2. Reboot

If keys do not work, add `acpi_osi=` option and `20-intel.conf` file

There was a kernel version with regression, where that kernel option did not work. But on current 3.19.0-18 it should work.

The problem is that kernel developers tried to do it that way that conf file had not been needed. But they did it with a regression for some Asus models. Now it should be fixed. But am not quite sure that correct patches reached all Ubuntu kernels.

So this issue is "in process", but workarounds should work in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Only installing the 3.19.0-18 kernel itself hadn't solved the problem, but adding `acpi_osi=` grub option and the `20-intel.conf` file afterwards solved it.

Comment: This means they spoiled 3.16 kernel. I wrote in launchpad NOT TO backport it, because it is a regression. But they did. But shortly they will backport a fix ))) But with 3.19 it is OK.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on an ASUS UX303LAB  :-(
I'm running 3.19.0-21-generic on Ubuntu 14.04. While it seems to work for people with the UX303LA models, there still seems to be a problem with the Broadwell version. `evtest` shows responses to the other `fn` keys, but nothing for the brightness keys.

Comment: did not work for me, 16.04 , asus gl552vw