# Brightness controll on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, brightness

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS in parallel with Win10.
I fixed the problem with NVIDIA card with GRUB command `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash nomodeset"`. 
But the problem is that I couldn't change the screen brightness. I used the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` statement, it worked but it failed with the command above. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This question is actually a duplicate of [Fn + F5 / F6 brightness keys not working on Asus R556L](https://askubuntu.com/q/812476/568304), but the most helpful answers for systems where backlight adjustment doesn't work out of the box can be found under [How to increase brightness in smaller steps?](https://askubuntu.com/q/103249/568304)

`xbacklight` is one option. [For me `acpilight` works best](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013231/568304), but it has to be set up manually, as there's no Ubuntu package AFAIK.